# Importing mysql gone wrong, Unexpected character (mariaDB)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb

Im quiet new to mariaDB. I have to migrate an mysql exported sql file to mariaDB. But it is not working.

I keep getting this error (it is a wordpress DB, nothing special)

```
731 were found during analysis.

Unexpected Character. (near ":" at position 4151)
Unexpected Character. (near "[" at position 4152)
Unexpected Character. (near "]" at position 4168)
Unexpected Character. (near ":" at position 4183)
Unexpected Character. (near "\" at position 5183)
```

SQL-query:

SQL-query:

```
INSERT INTO `wp1rfk1x_eg_item_skins` VALUES(37, 'Jimmy Carter', 'jimmy-carter', '{"eg-item-skin-element-last-id":"24","choose-layout":"masonry","show-content":"bottom","content-align":"left","element-x-ratio":"4","element-y-ratio":"3","cover-type":"full","container-background-color":"#ffffff","0":"Default","element-container-background-color-opacity":"0","cover-background-size":"cover","cover-background-repeat":"no-repeat","cover-background-image":"0","cover-background-image-url":"","full-bg-color":"#ffffff","full-padding":["30","30","27","30"],"full-border":["0","0","0","0"],"full-border-radius":["0","0","0","0"],"full-border-color":"#e5e5e5","full-border-style":"solid","content-bg-color":"#ffffff","content-padding":["27","0","0","0"],"content-border":["0","0","0","0"],"content-border-radius":["0","0","0","0"],"content-border-color":"#e5e5e5","content-border-style":"solid","all-shadow-used":"none","content-shadow-color":"#000000","content-shadow-alpha":"100","content-box-shadow":["0","3","6","1"],"cover-animation-top-type":"","cover-animation-delay-top":"0","cover-animation-top":"fade","cover-animation-center-type":"","cover-animation-delay-center":"0","cover-animation-center":"fade","cover-animation-bottom-type":"","cover-animation-delay-bottom":"0","cover-animation-bottom":"fade","cover-group-animation":"none","media-animation":"3dturnright","media-animation-delay":"8","google-fonts":["Droid+Serif:400,700","Open+Sans:400,600,700,800"]}', '[{"id":"0","order":"0","container":"c","settings":{"0":"","source":"text","enable-hover":"","font-size":"13","line-height":"15","color":"#363839","font-family":"\\"Open Sans\\"","font-weight":"800","text-decoration":"none","font-style":"","text-transform":"uppercase","display":"inline-block","text-align":"center","float":"left","clear":"both","margin":{"0":"0","1":"0","2":"0","3":"0"},"padding":{"0":"5","1":"10","2":"5","3":"10"},"background-color":"#ffffff","bg-alpha":"75","background-size":"cover","background-repeat":"no-repeat","shadow-color":"#000000","shadow-alpha":"100","box-shadow":{"0":"0","1":"0","2":"0","3":"0"},"border":{"0":"0","1":"0","2":"0","3":"0"},"border-radius":{"0":"0","1":"0","2":"0","3":"0"},"border-radius-unit":"px","border-color":"transparent","border-style":"none","css":"","font-size-hover":"13","line-height-hover":"14","color-hover":"#ffffff","font-family-hover":"","font-weight-hover":"700","text-decoration-hover":"none","font-style-hover":"","text-transform-hover":"uppercase","background-color-hover":"#ffffff","bg-alpha-hover":"15","background-size-hover":"cover","background-size-x-hover":"100","background-size-y-hover":"100","background-repeat-hover":"no-repeat","shadow-color-hover":"#000000","shadow-alpha-hover":"100","box-shadow-hover":{"0":"0","1":"0","2":"0","3":"0"},"border-hover":{"0":"0","1":"0","2":"0","3":"0"},"border-radius-hover":{"0":"0","1":"0","2":"0","3":"0"},"border-radius-unit-hover":"px","border-color-hover":"transparent","border-style-hover":"none","css-hover":"","hideunder":"0","transition":"skewright","delay":"15","link-type":"none","url-link":"","javascript-link":"","attribute":"","class":"","rel":"","padding-unit":"px","border-unit":"px","box-shadow-unit":"px","position":"relative","top-bottom":"0","left-right":"0","limit-type":"none","limit-num":"10","transition-type":"","tag-type":"div","force-important":"","align":"t_l","absolute-unit":"px","margin-unit":"px","source-separate":",","source-text":"I\'m a custom caption"}},{"id":"1","order":"0","container":"m","settings":{"0":"","source":"post","enable-hover":"on","font-size":"20","line-height":"25","color":"INSERT INTO `wp1rfk1x_eg_item_skins` VALUES(38, 'Ronald Reagan', 'ronald-reagan', '{"eg-item-skin-element-last-id":"8","choose-layout":"masonry","show-content":"bottom","content-align":"left","element-x-ratio":"4","element-y-ratio":"3","cover-type":"full","container-background-color":"transparent","0":"Default","element-container-background-color-opacity":"100","cover-background-size":"cover","cover-background-repeat":"no-repeat","cover-background-image":"0","cover-background-image-url":"","full-bg-color":"transparent","full-padding":["0","0","0","0"],"full-border":["0","0","0","0"],"full-border-radius":["0","0","0","0"],"full-border-color":"transparent","full-border-style":"none","full-overflow-hidden":"false","content-bg-color":"#ffffff","content-padding":["20","20","20","20"],"content-border":["0","0","0","0"],"content-border-radius":["0","0","0","0"],"content-border-color":"transparent","content-border-style":"none","all-shadow-used":"none","content-shadow-color":"#000000","content-shadow-alpha":"100","content-box-shadow":["0","0","0","0"],"cover-animation-top-type":"","cover-animation-delay-top":"0","cover-animation-top":"none","cover-animation-center-type":"out","cover-animation-delay-center":"4","cover-animation-center":"fade","cover-animation-bottom-type":"out","cover-animation-delay-bottom":"0","cover-animation-bottom":"fade","cover-group-animation":"none","media-animation":"none","media-animation-delay":"0"}', '[{"id":"0","order":"0","container":"tl","settings":{"0":"","source":"post","enable-hover":"","font-size":"13","line-height":"20","color":"#ffffff","font-family":"","font-weight":"700","text-decoration":"none","font-style":"","text-transform":"uppercase","display":"inline-block","text-align":"center","float":"left","clear":"both","margin":{"0":"0","1":"0","2":"0","3":"0"},"padding":{"0":"10","1":"20","2":"10","3":"20"},"background-color":"#4d384b","bg-alpha":"100","background-size":"cover","background-repeat":"no-repeat","shadow-color":"#000000","shadow-alpha":"100","box-shadow":{"0":"0","1":"0","2":"0","3":"0"},"border":{"0":"0","1":"0","2":"0","3":"0"},"border-radius":{"0":"0","1":"0","2":"0","3":"0"},"border-radius-unit":"px","border-color":"transparent","border-style":"none","css":"","font-size-hover":"13","line-height-hover":"14","color-hover":"#ffffff","font-family-hover":"","font-weight-hover":"700","text-decoration-hover":"none","font-style-hover":"","text-transform-hover":"uppercase","background-color-hover":"#ffffff","bg-alpha-hover":"15","background-size-hover":"cover","background-size-x-hover":"100","background-size-y-hover":"100","background-repeat-hover":"no-repeat","shadow-color-hover":"#000000","shadow-alpha-hover":"100","box-shadow-hover":{"0":"0","1":"0","2":"0","3":"0"},"border-hover":{"0":"0","1":"0","2":"0","3":"0"},"border-radius-hover":{"0":"0","1":"0","2":"0","3":"0"},"border-radius-unit-hover":"px","border-color-hover":"transparent","border-style-hover":"none","css-hover":"","hideunder":"0","transition":"slideup","delay":"6","link-type":"none","url-link":"","javascript-link":"","attribute":"","class":"","rel":"","padding-unit":"px","border-unit":"px","box-shadow-unit":"px","position":"relative","top-bottom":"0","left-right":"0","limit-type":"none","limit-num":"","transition-type":"out","tag-type":"div","force-important":"","align":"t_l","absolute-unit":"px","margin-unit":"px","source-separate":"","hide-on-video":"","show-on-sale":"","show-if-featured":"","source-post":"date_modified"}},{"id":"1","order":"0","container":"br","settings":{"0":"","source":"post","enable-hover":"","font-size":"20","line-height":"23","color":"#ffffff","font-family":"\\"Droid Serif\\"","font-weight":"300","text-decoration":"none","font-style":"","text-transform":"none","display":"block","text-align":"left","float":"none","clear":"both","margin":["0","0","10","10"],"padding":["5","10","5","10"],"background-color":"#ffffff","bg-alpha":"0","background-size":"cover","background-repeat":"no-repeat","shadow-color":"#000000","shadow-alpha":"100","box-shadow":["0","0","0","0"],"border":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius-unit":"px","border-color":"transparent","border-style":"none","css":"","font-size-hover":"13","line-height-hover":"14","color-hover":"#ffffff","font-family-hover":"","font-weight-hover":"700","text-decoration-hover":"none","font-style-hover":"","text-transform-hover":"uppercase","background-color-hover":"#ffffff","bg-alpha-hover":"15","background-size-hover":"cover","background-size-x-hover":"100","background-size-y-hover":"100","background-repeat-hover":"no-repeat","shadow-color-hover":"#000000","shadow-alpha-hover":"100","box-shadow-hover":["0","0","0","0"],"border-hover":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius-hover":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius-unit-hover":"px","border-color-hover":"transparent","border-style-hover":"none","css-hover":"","hideunder":"0","transition":"slidedown","delay":"15","link-type":"none","url-link":"","javascript-link":"","attribute":"","class":"","rel":"","padding-unit":"px","border-unit":"px","box-shadow-unit":"px","position":"relative","top-bottom":"0","left-right":"0","limit-type":"words","limit-num":"10","transition-type":"out","tag-type":"div","force-important":"","align":"t_l","absolute-unit":"px","margin-unit":"px","source-separate":",","source-post":"title"}},{"id":"2","order":"0","container":"m","settings":{"0":"","source":"post","enable-hover":"on","font-size":"12","line-height":"14","color":"#999999","font-family":"\\"Open Sans\\"","font-weight":"400","text-decoration":"none","font-style":"","text-transform":"none","display":"inline-block","text-align":"center","float":"none","clear":"none","margin":["0","20","0","0"],"padding":["0","0","0","0"],"background-color":"#ffffff","bg-alpha":"0","background-size":"cover","background-repeat":"no-repeat","shadow-color":"#000000","shadow-alpha":"100","box-shadow":["0","0","0","0"],"border":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius-unit":"px","border-color":"transparent","border-style":"none","css":"","font-size-hover":"12","line-height-hover":"14","color-hover":"#000000","font-family-hover":"\\"Open Sans\\"","font-weight-hover":"400","text-decoration-hover":"none","font-style-hover":"","text-transform-hover":"none","background-color-hover":"#ffffff","bg-alpha-hover":"0","background-size-hover":"cover","background-size-x-hover":"100","background-size-y-hover":"100","background-repeat-hover":"no-repeat","shadow-color-hover":"#000000","shadow-alpha-hover":"100","box-shadow-hover":["0","0","0","0"],"border-hover":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius-hover":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius-unit-hover":"px","border-color-hover":"transparent","border-style-hover":"none","css-hover":"","hideunder":"0","transition":"slideright","delay":"34","link-type":"none","url-link":"","javascript-link":"","attribute":"","class":"","rel":"","padding-unit":"px","border-unit":"px","box-shadow-unit":"px","position":"relative","top-bottom":"0","left-right":"0","limit-type":"none","limit-num":"10","transition-type":"","tag-type":"div","force-important":"true","align":"t_l","absolute-unit":"px","margin-unit":"px","source-separate":", ","border-hover-unit":"px","border-radius-hover-unit":"px","box-shadow-hover-unit":"px","border-unit-hover":"px","box-shadow-unit-hover":"px","source-post":"cat_list"}},{"id":"8","order":"0","container":"c","settings":{"0":"Default","source":"icon","enable-hover":"on","font-size":"20","line-height":"28","color":"#ffffff","font-family":"","font-weight":"400","text-decoration":"none","font-style":"","text-transform":"none","display":"inline-block","text-align":"center","float":"none","clear":"none","margin":["0","0","0","0"],"padding":["17","17","17","17"],"background-color":"#000000","bg-alpha":"100","background-size":"cover","background-repeat":"no-repeat","shadow-color":"#000000","shadow-alpha":"100","box-shadow":["0","0","0","0"],"border":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius":["60","60","60","60"],"border-radius-unit":"px","border-color":"#ffffff","border-style":"solid","font-size-hover":"20","line-height-hover":"28","color-hover":"#000000","font-family-hover":"","font-weight-hover":"400","text-decoration-hover":"none","font-style-hover":"","text-transform-hover":"none","background-color-hover":"#ffffff","bg-alpha-hover":"100","background-size-hover":"cover","background-size-x-hover":"100","background-size-y-hover":"100","background-repeat-hover":"no-repeat","shadow-color-hover":"#000000","shadow-alpha-hover":"100","box-shadow-hover":["0","0","0","0"],"border-hover":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius-hover":["60","60","60","60"],"border-radius-unit-hover":"px","border-color-hover":"#ffffff","border-style-hover":"solid","hideunder":"0","transition":"rotatescale","delay":"10","link-type":"post","url-link":"","javascript-link":"","padding-unit":"px","border-unit":"px","box-shadow-unit":"px","position":"relative","top-bottom":"0","left-right":"0","source-separate":",","limit-type":"none","limit-num":"10","transition-type":"","attribute":"","class":"","rel":"","tag-type":"div","force-important":"true","align":"t_l","absolute-unit":"px","margin-unit":"px","border-hover-unit":"px","border-radius-hover-unit":"px","box-shadow-hover-unit":"px","border-unit-hover":"px","box-shadow-unit-hover":"px","source-icon":"eg-icon-link"}},{"id":"4","order":"1","container":"m","settings":{"0":"Default","source":"post","limit-type":"none","limit-num":"10","enable-hover":"on","font-size":"12","line-height":"14","color":"#999","font-family":"\\"Open Sans\\"","font-weight":"400","text-decoration":"none","font-style":"","text-transform":"none","position":"relative","align":"t_l","absolute-unit":"px","top-bottom":"0","left-right":"0","display":"inline-block","text-align":"center","float":"none","clear":"none","margin":["0","0","0","0"],"padding":["0","0","0","0"],"background-color":"#ffffff","bg-alpha":"0","background-size":"cover","background-repeat":"no-repeat","shadow-color":"#000000","shadow-alpha":"100","box-shadow":["0","0","0","0"],"border":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius-unit":"px","border-color":"transparent","border-style":"none","font-size-hover":"12","line-height-hover":"14","color-hover":"#000000","font-family-hover":"\\"Open Sans\\"","font-weight-hover":"400","text-decoration-hover":"none","font-style-hover":"","text-transform-hover":"none","background-color-hover":"#ffffff","bg-alpha-hover":"0","background-size-hover":"cover","background-size-x-hover":"100","background-size-y-hover":"100","background-repeat-hover":"no-repeat","shadow-color-hover":"#000000","shadow-alpha-hover":"100","box-shadow-hover":["0","0","0","0"],"border-hover":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius-hover":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius-unit-hover":"px","border-color-hover":"transparent","border-style-hover":"none","hideunder":"0","transition":"slideright","transition-type":"","split":"full","delay":"34","link-type":"none","url-link":"","javascript-link":"","tag-type":"div","force-important":"true","attribute":"","class":"","rel":"","padding-unit":"px","border-unit":"px","box-shadow-unit":"px","margin-unit":"px","source-separate":",","border-hover-unit":"px","border-radius-hover-unit":"px","box-shadow-hover-unit":"px","border-unit-hover":"px","box-shadow-unit-hover":"px","source-post":"num_comments"}},{"id":"5","order":"2","container":"m","settings":{"0":"Default","source":"post","limit-type":"words","limit-num":"20","enable-hover":"","font-size":"15","line-height":"20","color":"#444444","font-family":"\\"Droid Serif\\"","font-weight":"300","text-decoration":"none","font-style":"","text-transform":"none","position":"relative","align":"t_l","absolute-unit":"px","top-bottom":"0","left-right":"0","display":"block","text-align":"left","float":"none","clear":"none","margin":["7","0","0","0"],"padding":["15","0","0","0"],"background-color":"#ffffff","bg-alpha":"0","background-size":"cover","background-repeat":"no-repeat","shadow-color":"#000000","shadow-alpha":"100","box-shadow":["0","0","0","0"],"border":["1","0","0","0"],"border-radius":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius-unit":"px","border-color":"#e5e5e5","border-style":"solid","font-size-hover":"13","line-height-hover":"14","color-hover":"#ffffff","font-family-hover":"","font-weight-hover":"300","text-decoration-hover":"none","font-style-hover":"","text-transform-hover":"none","background-color-hover":"#ffffff","bg-alpha-hover":"15","background-size-hover":"cover","background-size-x-hover":"100","background-size-y-hover":"100","background-repeat-hover":"no-repeat","shadow-color-hover":"#000000","shadow-alpha-hover":"100","box-shadow-hover":["0","0","0","0"],"border-hover":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius-hover":["0","0","0","0"],"border-radius-unit-hover":"px","border-color-hover":"transparent","border-style-hover":"none","hideunder":"0","transition":"slideright","transition-type":"","split":"full","delay":"34","link-type":"none","url-link":"","javascript-link":"","tag-type":"div","force-important":"","attribute":"","class":"","rel":"","padding-unit":"px","border-unit":"px","box-shadow-unit":"px","margin-unit":"px","source-post":"excerpt"}}]', NULL)
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Ronald Reagan', 'ronald-reagan', '{"eg-item-skin-element-last-id":"8","choose-la' at line 1

I also tried exporting it as CSV first but that also did not work.

Comment: I don't think this info is enough for us to be able to help you, since we don't know what string is around those positions.

Comment: The SQL query is not complete and the error is given (#1064) is from a different query...

Comment: I added a full query. But this is everything i have.

Comment: What comes immediately before `'Ronald...`?

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong in the export.
For instance, somewhere in your query, you can see the following:
`"line-height":"25","color":"INSERT INTO ...`
This is of course not correct and you need to look for stuff like this to fix it, or make a new dump directly from PHPAdmin

I hope this answer helped you

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already exported directly from PHPmyAdmin but still got the same error. Because I was in a hurry, i exported the website from wordpress its self and imported into the new host. Took me a bit longer but it worked. But if it went wrong in the export like you say, then why am I able to import it into mysql DB but not mariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

this is exactly what happened to me.  When i tried to upload an sql file to network solutions phpmyadmin, i get that list of similar errors.  To test i uploaded to bluehost phpmyadmin.  NO errors.  This may not be a user error, but a hosting error.  DON"T TRASH THAT SQL FILE.

I would suggest talking to the network admin/hosting provider.  I created a new database in my network solutions account and the import worked fine.

Comment: Did you also tried to upload your sql file into mariaDB and got that error? Because when I upload into phpmyadmin mysql, it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I encountered the same problem, and manage to fix it. Just wanted to share my solution and maybe it could help some people out there.

I found out that my database size is larger than my allowed 'upload limit'. So I change my 'upload_max_filesize', and 'post_max_size' in the php.ini file, and it works. If you are using XAMPP or something similar, don't forget to restart it.